# Create my own Linux using Ubuntu Source

Tags: raspbian, linux

Customize Linux Ubuntu or Debian for my raspberry pi. How can I remove packages and Applications from the ubuntu or Debian? And Also I would like to know if its possible to modify the GUI (graphich interface) of the ubuntu?

Do i need to download the source code on my workstation and than start developing it or should I do all the necessery changes on a installed Ubuntu?

Once I'm finished how can I create a installation out if it? Or how can I flash my device with an image?

Comment: Welcome -- but this is not really [a pi-specific question](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic),  general linux questions belong on our larger sibling site [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).   There is also [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/).  I suggest you have a look round there about adding/removing packages, customizing the desktop, etc.   You may find [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87184/25985) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment#Desktop_environments_for_the_X_Window_System) enlightening regarding some fundamental concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raspbian is already optimized enough to make it work optimally for RPi. You can have a look at `minibian` which is nothing but an unoffical stripped down version of raspbian.

Also customizing requires a good knowledge of linux internals. And as far as, installing / removing package is concerned, you may use `sudo apt-get install` or `sudo apt-get remove`. :)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the greate answer. How do I modify the GUI (Userinterface)? Is that even possible to change the design? And should I do these changes on a installed raspbian or I have to download the sourcecode, build it and than install it?

Comment: The default desktop environment on Raspbian (the Debian variant) is [LXDE](http://lxde.org/), which has lots of docs, a forum, etc.   You are not bound to stick with that, however, as most of the other major (and not so major) DE's and WM's are available in Raspbian.   I don't know what the default is on the Ubuntu ARM port, but the logic is exactly the same.   People who like things highly configurable via text files are often drawn to the openbox WM.   You probably don't need or want to have to start getting into source code modifications.